# Free open source photo editing software with similar functionality and interface as Photoshop?

Tags: open-source, photography, image-editor, privacy, photoshop

I am looking for photo editing software that is as similar as possible to Adobe Photoshop.

The reason why I want it to be as similar is because if I ever want to do a job which requires Photoshop knowledge, it would be an advantage to be experienced with software the only differs minimally, to shorten relearning a much as possible. Also, I doubt Photoshop and similar software, such as Illustrator, are privacy respecting.

Does there exist such free, open source software?

I've seen the following recommendations that are privacy respecting:

- GIMP - The Free & Open Source Image Editor.
- Krita - Krita is a free and open source digital painting application
- Czkawka - Multi functional app to find duplicates and similar images etc.
- DigiKam - Awesome Professional Photo Management with the Power of Open Source.
- Inkscape - Inkscape is a free and open-source vector graphics editor used to create vector images.

Are any of these a good alternative for Photoshop, as I have described?

I'm thinking of digital painting as an application. So the aspects and tools of PS that are associated with it, such as brushes, layers and so on, should have similar UI.

Comment: Why not try them all out and see which one suits you since they are free? Anyway, GIMP is considered the most similar to Photoshop.

Comment: Please list the options which are critical for the job(s). PS have so many options and tools...

Comment: In the past Adobe has been very aggressively defending their proprietary rights, so I think it will be rather unlikely that there will be a Photoshop lookalike ever. Maybe they even defend their key combinations.

Comment: Gimp is great! I am using it for years!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should give it a try to https://www.photopea.com/ it's not fully open source (but it has a repo: https://github.com/photopea/photopea ). It has a similar user experience to Adobe Photoshop.

Comment: W/o list of required options this answer is shoot in the dark. Moreover this software do not support RAW files which may be (for me for example) critical.

Comment: It says that support RAW files - at the very front page if you open it.

Comment: It doesn't  support Tough TG-5, I try it. On Git page i see: Raw: DNG, NEF, CR2, ARW, RAF, GPR, 3FR, FFF.

Comment: FYI, Adobe Lightroom didn't even support ORF files (or not from all cameras, at least) a few years before this. And you could do RAW processing with the Olympus software as an additional step in your workflow. Just a counter-example of why this was a confusing reason to make a blanket statement "it doesn't support RAW files."

Answer (score 0):

https://www.photopea.com/ is good, but I will suggest you try [Photo scape X](http://x.photoscape.org/) or [Krita](https://krita.org/en/), both are free and similar to photoshop

Source: [Free Adobe Photoshop Alternative](https://developingdaily.com/article/technology/free-adobe-photoshop-alternative/266)